# FITS metadata problem

Tags: export, metadata, fits-format

Looks to me that the FITS Export is borged.  Here is the problem:

When I export out images with accustom metadata into a FITS file, Mathematica truncates and overwrites it.

Here is the metadata I got with Import:

```
In[530]:= (* Read fits file metadata. *)
fpa425meta=Import["img_a_425.fits.seg.fit","Metadata"]
Out[530]= {SIMPLE->True,BITPIX->16,NAXIS->3,NAXIS1->256,NAXIS2->256,NAXIS3->1000,BZERO->32768.,BSCALE->1.,INSTRUME->KAF 4200,PMISGAIN->1,FILE->img_001,OBJECT->KOI,IMAGETYP->emccd speckle,FILTER->754.0 nm,OBSERVER->E. Horch, S. Howell, M. Everett, D. Ciardi,TELESCOP->Gemini-N,DETECTOR->Andor iXon EMCCD,EXPTIME->50,DATE-OBS->21/12/104,TIME-OBS->03:17:01,ORIGIN->PMIS Image Processing Software,ORIGIN->Copyright (C) 1991-1998 GKR Computer Consulting}
```

I make this modification to it:

```
In[554]:= fpa425metaPos=Position[fpa425meta,"NAXIS3"]
Out[554]= {{6,1}}

In[555]:= fpa425metaPos[[1,2]]++
Out[555]= 1

In[558]:= fpa425meta=ReplacePart[fpa425meta,fpa425metaPos->Length[ext1fpa425]]
Out[558]= {SIMPLE->True,BITPIX->16,NAXIS->3,NAXIS1->256,NAXIS2->256,NAXIS3->3,BZERO->32768.,BSCALE->1.,INSTRUME->KAF 4200,PMISGAIN->1,FILE->img_001,OBJECT->KOI,IMAGETYP->emccd speckle,FILTER->754.0 nm,OBSERVER->E. Horch, S. Howell, M. Everett, D. Ciardi,TELESCOP->Gemini-N,DETECTOR->Andor iXon EMCCD,EXPTIME->50,DATE-OBS->21/12/104,TIME-OBS->03:17:01,ORIGIN->PMIS Image Processing Software,ORIGIN->Copyright (C) 1991-1998 GKR Computer Consulting}
```

Then I write my expression out into the fits file with the modified Metadata:

```
Export["/Users/jancsi/Documents/MasterDegree/Theses/programs/scsu/Results/425/Exported/LessMin1sigMet.fits",{ext1fpa425},"Metadata"->fpa425meta];
```

When I read back the Metadata, I am getting something totally different:

```
In[560]:= fpa425metaMod=Import["/Users/jancsi/Documents/MasterDegree/Theses/programs/scsu/Results/425/Exported/LessMin1sigMet.fits","Metadata"]
Out[560]= {SIMPLE->{True,Normal FITS file},BITPIX->{-32,Bits/pixel, negative is floating point},NAXIS->{3,Dimensionality of data},NAXIS1->256,NAXIS2->256,NAXIS3->3,EXTENDED->{True,Extensions may be present},PCOUNT->{0,Deprecated},GCOUNT->{1,Deprecated},BSCALE->{1,Scale factor},BZERO->{0,Zero factor real=tape*bscale+bzero},CREATOR->Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com}
<nyassz>
```

Sent this to Wolfram Support who answered:

> Unfortunately in the current version of Mathematica the
>   metadata would be overwritten when exporting in the FITS format, and
>   this default behaviour cannot be changed. I am forwarding your message
>   to the existing incidence report and you will be informed for any
>   updates on this topic.

Now, I do not know how long it will take Wolfram to comply with FITS 3.0 specification already published 4 years ago.  So I am open to any suggestion which way can I get around this problem.  I need to write out the "right" FITS header, because other programs rely on it and right now they bombing out on Floating Point exeption /divison by 0/

Right now I am thinking just to use `BinaryRead` and avoid `Import` and also use `BinaryWrite` to write the results back after some manipulations, but I am open to any other good suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, you could consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). it would facilitate other people trying to answer your question if you [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to make it more readable.

Comment: [This](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DevelopingAnExportConverter.html) is not going to be easier than the Binary thing you suggest, but at least you can pack it as an Exporter